# Download file from server with save dialog electronjs

Tags: electron

I am developing electron app. I am looking for way in which when user clicks on button then user can download the file from server at specific location ( save dialog).

I have tried various ways but none of them worked. I am looking for code. Thanks

Comment: Show your code and tell us about your problem

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/8839edb51e2b11e93a25ae3bb1d83166

Here's a minimal Gist example, openable from [Electron Fiddle](https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle).

The crux of the code is that you should be using the `dialog.showSaveDialog` API to let the user choose a path for your file, and then use your preferred JavaScript method to write the file from the server to your filesystem.

IPC is used such that the button can tell the main process (which triggers the dialog and handles the filesystem operation) to do begin its work.

Answer (score 0):

A good option would be using Electron-dl (https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl). They present several options according to your usage.